# Objective-C Using Accelerometer (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, accelerometer

I have a class called MainGame, which is defined like this in my .h:

```
@interface MainGame : Renderer <UIAccelerometerDelegate>
```

Then later in my .m I have this:

```
- (void) accelerometer: (UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate: (UIAcceleration *)acceleration {
    // here I would read values like accelerometer.x
    NSLog(@"accelerated!!1");
}
```

Am I doing it right?

Currently I'm only testing in iPhone simulator, I'm going to buy the apple $99 developer thing soon. It doesn't log "accelerated!!1", but I'm guessing that's because I'm not running it on an actual device yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct. The iPhone simulator does not provide Accelerometer services.

You may find this useful: http://code.google.com/p/accelerometer-simulator/wiki/Home

There is also this, which allows you to use phone input in the simulator (warning, App Store link, also has a Lite version): http://itunes.com/app/iSimulate

Comment: Thanks.

I tried downloading iSimulate Lite but it keeps saying "No computers were found with a listening iSimulate-ready application."

I'm using an iPod Touch, and it's connected to my Mac, and iPhone simulator is running with an app in it

What do I do..? D:

Comment: You can't just run it - it needs some small changes to your XCode project to make it work.

Step by step instructions are here: http://www.vimov.com/isimulate/documentation/#using

Comment: Wow, it works like a gem. I just purchased it, and it's great! Thanks a lot :D